# Would it be possible to create a script which would search and highlight multiple words within a Google doc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I would like to be able to have the ability to search up to 30+ phrases within a Google doc. Currently I have to do this process manually with find and replace tool.

But could a script automate this process in someway where it would search for the words and highlight them within the doc for me to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to highlight (by highlight, I assume you mean changing the background color) certain sentences if they are present in your document.

#### Solution:

- For each sentence, use [Body.findText(sentence)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) to find its first occurrence in the document.
- Retrieve the start and end offset of the resulting [RangeElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element).
- Check whether the corresponding element can be edited as text and obtain a text version of it (see [editAsText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#editastext)).
- Change the background color using [setBackgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBackgroundColor(Integer,Integer,String)).

#### Code sample:

```
const sentences = ["First sentence", "Second"]; // Your sentences

function highlightSentences() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  sentences.forEach(sentence => {
    const rangeElement = body.findText(sentence);
    if (rangeElement) {
      const startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
      const endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      const element = rangeElement.getElement();
      if (element.editAsText) {
        const textElement = element.editAsText();
        textElement.setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffset, "#fcfc03");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I do have a follow up question. Currently I do have this script running however it doesn't highlight all the words within the doc in some instances. E.g if I ask it to highlight "England" it will only highlight some of the words not all. Some of the docs I have can be 100+ pages so would need it to highlight all words

Comment: @Raj You mean there's, for example, many instances of `England`, and it's only highlighting some? If you want to highlight all instances of a certain word/sentence, you should add another loop and iteratively call [Text.findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern,-from), so that the search is done for each iteration starting from the last found instance. If you need help with that, I'd suggest you to post a new question.